# Foundation for emails: Add code after Inky and Inlining

Tags: node.js, zurb-foundation, zurb-ink, inky

I'm using foundation for emails 2.

I'm looking to insert a piece of code into the final rendered email, after all the node tasks have run, specifically after the email has been inlined. As inlining breaks the particular snippet I'm looking to insert.

Can I insert a custom piece of code per email, with the help of panini templating?

How might I achieve this with a node task?
Or is there another better method to use here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{{raw}}} your code {{{/raw}}}` or `<raw> your code </raw>` to output any needed strings which should not be changed by Inky.

And you can add another Gulp task to replace any custom string or add a custom Handlebars helper.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work sadly. It looks like the CSS inliner is still running on the snippet. Essentially it's a litmus tracking snippet. I'm trying to use Panini to insert unique identifiers. The inline breaks the Litmus snippet.

Comment: Can you provide a small demo project which uses the latest dependencies so I can check it there? Debugging this way is not easy.